# Distances of points on geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry

**The setting:**

-Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and let $\pi:E \rightarrow M$ be its universal covering with the pullback metric.

-Let $\alpha,\beta:[0,1] \rightarrow E $ be two minimal geodesics (i.e. length$(\alpha) = d(\alpha(0),\alpha(1)$) in the covering with the same "starting point" $\alpha(0) = \beta(0)$. Here, $d$ is the usual "shortest-path distance".

**What I'm trying to understand/prove now:**

if $d(\alpha(t),\beta(t)) = c$ for a $t \in (0,1)$ and $d(\alpha(s),\beta(s)) < c$ for all $s \in (0,t)$, then d$(\pi \circ \alpha(t),\pi \circ \beta(t)) = c$.

I'm a bit stuck here at the moment. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you missing something? Consider $E=\mathbb{R}$, $M=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, $\pi(t)= t\mod 1$, $\alpha(t)=t$ and $\beta(t)=-t$.